# Check to see if "dpkg --configure -a" needs to be run

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

When something goes wrong in the middle of a dpkg configuration we need to run dpkg --configure -a before installing a new package.

Is there a way to check if "dpkg --configure -a" needs to be run? Any files we can inspect?

Answer (score 2):

Check the output of 
   `dpkg -l|grep $packagename` . In the first column, you can see the status of the package. To understand what these flags mean, you can check the output of `dpkg -l|head -3`. First letter is desired state, the second letter is the package status.

For example, the status flag `iF` means installed, half-configured. In this case, you will need to issue a `dpkg --configure` for the package.

Answer (score 0):

```
dpkg -l | grep -E '^[A-Za-z][A-Z]'
```

If you have any output, it means you need to `dpkg --configure -a`.